# How do I get this code to multiply the numbers in the array together?

Tags: arrays

My goal is to get the code to output the product of all the numbers in the array. What do i need to change or add to make the code multiply the numbers in the array together. I am in the process of learning this stuff and got stuck.

Here is my current code:

```
function start(){

    var arr = [1, 8, 3, 4, 2, 9];

    var pro = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var cur = arr[i];
        pro += cur;
    }
    println(pro);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `pro += cur` to `pro *= cur`. The way you're doing it actually produces the sum. However, do be sure in the future to specify which language you're using, because answers to other questions can vary!